# Double tooltips on one point in Google Charts

Tags: charts, tooltip, google-visualization

I am creating a Line Chart in Google Charts. The data in the chart is real simple, it is normal integer values, each with a Date. Along with this each point is to have tooltips.

Currently I have configured the charts object so that there is either a tooltip when hovering a point, or when the user selects a point. What I want to achieve is to have both. So that the user can get a small amount of data when hovering, but a more detailed report when the item is clicked.

When checking the documentation it seems that when triggering the option;

```
var options = { trigger: 'selection' }
```

this completely disables the hover trigger of a point. Is it possible to achieve multiple tooltips?
Setting two columns in the datatable to;

```
dt.addColumn({type:'string',role:'tooltip'});
```

only results in the error;

```
Only one data column with role 'tooltip' per series is allowed
```

**Note**: I do not wish to use the "multiple select" option, `selectionMode: 'multiple'`, since this only works on seperate points.

Comment: Most charts support setting the `tooltip.trigger` option to `'both'`, which will spawn a tooltip on mouseover and on select.

Comment: Yes, it seems you can! Nice. Now I just need to figure out of I can seperate the information shown.